# Best way to re-deploy NodeJS API on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ecs

[image]

I have deployed my NodeJS Express API to AWS ECS

I created :

- cluster
- cluster service
- task definition
- ECR

If I need to deploy another API for testing/development, do I need re-create these :

- cluster
- cluster service
- task definition
- ECR

or I can just create another **cluster service** ?

Answer (score 1):

To run a seperate application on an AWS ECS cluster as a separate service you'll need a

1. [Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html)
2. [Service Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html)
3. [Each application should have it's own ECR repository but still be in the same ECR registry.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/what-is-ecr.html)

If the cluster is too small to run all of the services tasks at the same time you can also [scale the cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scale_cluster.html)

> serviceName
>   The name of your service. Up to 255 letters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers, hyphens, and underscores are allowed. Service names must be unique within a >cluster, but you can have similarly named services in multiple clusters within a >region or across multiple regions.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: Yes
>   taskDefinition
>   The family and revision (family:revision) or full ARN of the task definition to run in your service. If a revision is not specified, the latest ACTIVE revision is >used.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: Yes
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateService.html